# What does $I$ mean in $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Quotient ring of a ring $R$ by an ideal $I$
The quotient group of the additive group of $R$ by the subgroup $I$, with multiplication 
$$(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$$
The quotient turns out to be a ring and is denoted by $R/I$.
I specifically don't understand why 
$$(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$$
is true and what exactly is $I$ in this multiplication doing? I am not particularly clear about the equivalence relation for this sort of multiplication even though I have read some stuff about it on the books related to the subject. I hope somebody explains this thing in the other way than then one explained in the books.

Comment: The equation is true because it is the **definition** of multiplication in $R/I$.

Comment: @5xum Is it? Can't we define the product $AB$ as $\{ab|a\in A,b\in B\}$?

Comment: @JackM We can, but we don't. The quotient ring $R/I$ is, by definition, the set of cosets of a given equivalence relation, with multiplication defined as $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to model the underlying set of the quotient ring $R/I$ is by taking it to be the *cosets* of $I$, or equivalently the *equivalence classes* of the equivalence relation defined by $I$.

The typical way of specifying a coset of $I$ is by identifying an element of the coset. If $a$ is an element and we let $\bar{a}$ denote the coset containing $a$, then

$$ \bar{a} = \{ a + i \mid i \in I \} $$

It is common to use the notation $a + I$ to denote this set.

Note that $a \neq b$ does not mean $a+I \neq b +I$; if $a$ and $b$ lie in the same coset (i.e. are congruent modulo $I$), then $a + I = b + I$.

---

The formula $(a+I)(b+I) = ab+I$ is simply the *definition* of multiplication in the quotient ring. You also define $(a+I) + (b+I) = (a+b) + I$.

Note one needs to check these are well-defined: i.e. if $a+I = c+I$ and $b+I = d+I$, then you need to verify $ab+I = cd+I$ and $(a+b)+I = (c+d)+I$.

Incidentally, to complete the basic analysis of the construction, one should also check:

- That $R/I$ with these operations satisfies the ring axioms.
- The quotient map $R \to R/I$ given by $a \mapsto a+I$ is a ring homomorphism.
- The kernel of the quotient map is precisely the ideal $I$.